# Get notified when a question you've voted to reopen is reopened

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-reopen

I'd like (the option) to be notified when a question I've voted to reopen is actually reopened.  Having to keep track of good questions that I intend to answer and to keep checking back to see if they've been reopened so that I can provide an answer is too much effort.

Comment: I assume a re-open is seen as activity and as such you should be able to spot them if you marked them as a favorite by the blue thingy on your favorite tab in your activity-profile. But that is not a *real* notification.

Comment: You can visit http://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=reopen and scan down to see which titles no longer indicate closure.

Comment: @Martin Smith:  Thanks, but many of those are questions I don't think I've ever looked at, let alone voted to reopen.

Comment: Assuming you are logged into SO as yourself that is the list of questions you have voted to reopen according to the database. Do you have an example question that is now reopened that you don't remember?

Comment: Here's an example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161597/swift-float-type-floating-point-precision  Another clue that something's wrong is that I almost always add a comment when I vote to re-open, explaining why I think it was wrong to close it.

Comment: Is there any example that is reopened that you don't remember? That was never successfully reopened so the list of reopen voters isn't displayed.

Comment: Nope, I remember all the ones that were successfully reopened.

Comment: It's interesting that some are on the list more than once.  For example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452530/how-to-render-a-rainbow-spectrum is listed twice for me.

Answer (score 3):

I like this idea, because having questions closed can be discouraging (especially for new users). If a user puts in the effort to edit their question into good shape, I'd like to see them rewarded with a good answer. This request should help support that.

However, I'd like to add another detail as well. You specified that it should be optional, and I'd like to clarify that (I think) it should be optional on a *per-question* basis, not an all-or-nothing opt-in. I go through the reopen review queue frequently, and I think getting a notification for every question I vote to reopen would create noise in reviewers' inboxes. I'd like to be able to select specific questions to receive notifications for.